# is it possible to get same colour for the FG and BG?

Tags: gimp, layers, gradient, contrast

I have imported a black and white picture and applied a layer mask to it with some gradients and soft brush applications. Unfortunately, there is too much difference in colour between the 2.

Is there a way to reduce this?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Hello, can you tell us what you have tried? You could use a variety of adjustment layers and use a clipping mask to change the contrast of just that area.

Comment: @AndrewH I am new to GIMP so still learning. I have used the paintbrush with hardness of 20 but somehow I need to change the colour black to be the same as the BG.

Answer (score 0):

If the black and white part is on its own layer, you could add a couple of colour adjustments.

First use a Brightness and Contrast adjustment, reduce the brightness and increase the contrast, then do a Colorize adjustment to colourise the image, using the eyedropper to sample the colour from the a dark brown part of the image, then change the saturation and lightness sliders to get a match.

An example

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it and get back to you!